# using xmlstarlet to parse a list in a specific order

Tags: xml, bash, sorting, xslt, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to use xmlstarlet sel to list the disk partitions I need to create from an xml file that list them in ascending block position on disk (example : https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/blob/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/doc/examples/disk-layout-complex.xml)
This file is generated by dumping an installed system that has to be replicated. User can then replace size with "*" for partition he wants to be adapted to new disk.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
    local IFS=;
    DISK_DEV=sda
    DISKS_LAYOUT_FILE=/tmp/disk-layout-complex.xml
    cd /tmp
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/finley/SystemImager/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/doc/examples/disk-layout-complex.xml
    xmlstarlet sel -t -m "config/disk[@dev=\"${DISK_DEV}\"]/part" -v "concat(@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@id,';',@p_name,';',@flags,';',@lvm_group,';',@raid_dev)" -n ${DISKS_LAYOUT_FILE} | sed '/^\s*$/d' |\
    while read P_NUM P_SIZE P_TYPE P_ID P_NAME P_FLAGS P_LVM_GROUP P_RAID_DEV
    do
        # process partitions creation.
        echo "Creating partition $P_NUM of size $P_SIZE tpye $P_TYPE"
    done
```

The above xmlstarlet will produce the following output that is then processed by the while read loop:

```
    1;500;primary;;;boot;;
    3;4096;primary;;;;;;
    4;*;extended;;;;;;
    7;4096;logical;;;;;;
    5;*;logical;;;;;;
    6;2048;logical;;;;;;
    2;1024;primary;;;swap;;
```

After line 3 (partition #4) is processed, there is no space left on disk, The loop will process line 4 (partition #7) and will fail with no space left on disk.

The problem is for variable size partition (use 100% ("*" in the file)). If one is listed before other remaining ones (part 4 in the above case), then, it is created with full remaining space, leaving no space on disk to process the last ones. Thus, for example, it is not possible to put a primary swap partition at the end of a disk with a / partition that has a variable size.

Q: Is there a clever way to use xmlstarlet sel to list partitions in the following order:

list all primary and extended partition in same order as written in the xml file until a partition with size "*" is seen;

- keep this variable size partition in mind
- then list from the end in reverse order the other partitions
- and finally print the variable size partition
- repeat operation with logical partitions if any

For all partition, add a field stating if it was listed in order or reverse order so I can know if I have to create partition relative to beginning of free space or relative to end of free space. (variable partition would be tagged as normal order as they would be created starting at beginning of free space)

For the listed example (disk-layout-complex.xml), this would list partitions to create in the following order:
(below, the output of xmlstarlet that would then be processed by a while read loop similar to the above code but with one more preceding read argument OFFSET_CREATE that would read the normal/reverse value)

```
    normal;1;500;primary;;;boot;;
    normal;3;4096;primary;;;;;;
    reverse;2;1024;primary;;;swap;;
    normal;4;*;extended;;;;;;
    normal;7;4096;logical;;;;;;
    reverse;6;2048;logical;;;;;;
    normal;5;*;logical;;;;;;
```

Processing the above xmlstarlet output would never trigger a situation were there are some partition to create while disk has no space left because a partition was created with 100% remainiong space.

I'm processing this within a specially crafted initrd, so I only have access to most common utils like sed/grep/bash2/xmlstarlet/awk. no perl, no python, no language that needs libraries in general.

I'm pretty convinced that there is a solution that does most of the job if not all, but I'm far not enough skilled to even evaluate if it can be done this way. I think I can achieve that in pure bash, but this will be far less elegant.

Comment: File is too big by 760 chars to fit comment.
I've edited the code example for more convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer is the following.

```
<!— Sample cut, relevant for this question —>
<config>
      <disk dev="/dev/sda" label_type="msdos" unit_of_measurement="MiB">
              <part num="1" size="500" p_type="primary" flags="boot" />
              <part num="3" size="4096" p_type="primary" />
              <part num="4" size="*" p_type="extended" />
              <part num="7" size="4096" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="5" size="*" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="6" size="2048" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="2" size="1024" p_type="primary" flags="swap" />
      </disk>
</config>
```

We want the following output in order to list partition in an order such as we can create partitions in order of apearance on the disk. The partition with a size of '*' will occupy all remaining space. So it must be created in the end.

Thus we need to create the following partition in sequence. (beginning and end are reference telling if we need to create the partition relatinve to beginning of available space or relative to the end of available space)

```
/dev/sda;end;2;1024;MiB;primary;;;swap;;
/dev/sda;beginning;1;500;MiB;primary;;;boot;;
/dev/sda;beginning;3;4096;MiB;primary;;;;;
/dev/sda;beginning;4;*;MiB;extended;;;;;
/dev/sda;end;6;2048;MiB;logical;;;;;
/dev/sda;beginning;7;4096;MiB;logical;;;;;
/dev/sda;beginning;5;*;MiB;logical;;;;;
```

It is obtained by running the sxl tranformation file with:

```
xmlstarlet tr do_part.xsl ./disk-layout-complex.xml
```

And now the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Call me with:
     xmlstarlet tr do_part.xsl disk-layout.xml

     Output: List of partitions to create in order.
        Each line list the following values separated by semicolons:
        - disk device
        - creation reference
        - partition number
        - partition size
        - partition size unit
        - partition type
        - partition id
        - partition name
        - partition flags
        - lvm group it belongs to
        - raid device it belongs to

      Author: Olivier LAHAYE (c) 2019
      Licence: GPLv2
-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/config/disk"> <!-- We are loking for disk informations only -->
    <!-- For each disk block -->
    <xsl:call-template name="PrintPartition"> <!-- Compute primary or extended partitions to create -->
      <xsl:with-param name="index"><xsl:value-of select="count(part)"/></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="reference">end</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="type">primary|extended</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="PrintPartition"> <!-- then, compute logical partitions to create -->
      <xsl:with-param name="index"><xsl:value-of select="count(part)"/></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="reference">end</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="type">logical</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template> <!-- We're done -->

  <!-- Main recursive template that will dump partitions to create for the matched disk -->
  <xsl:template name="PrintPartition">
    <xsl:param name="index"/> <!-- partition node number within disk item-->
    <xsl:param name="reference"/> <!-- beginning or end: should we create partition relative from beginning or from end of free space -->
    <xsl:param name="type"/> <!-- type of partitions -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$index=1">
        <xsl:if test="contains($type,part[position()=$index]/@p_type)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@dev,';',$reference,';',part[position()=$index]/@num,';',part[position()=$index]/@size,';',@unit_of_measurement,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_type,';',part[position()=$index]/@id,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_name,';',part[position()=$index]/@flags,';',part[position()=$index]/@lvm_group,';',part[position()=$index]/@raid_dev,'&#10;')"/> <!-- write partition information -->
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains($type,part[position()=$index]/@p_type) and part[position()=$index]/@size!='*'">
        <xsl:if test="$reference='end'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@dev,';',$reference,';',part[position()=$index]/@num,';',part[position()=$index]/@size,';',@unit_of_measurement,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_type,';',part[position()=$index]/@id,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_name,';',part[position()=$index]/@flags,';',part[position()=$index]/@lvm_group,';',part[position()=$index]/@raid_dev,'&#10;')"/> <!-- write partition information -->
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="PrintPartition">
          <xsl:with-param name="index"><xsl:value-of select="number($index)-1"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="reference"><xsl:value-of select="$reference"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="$reference='beginning'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@dev,';',$reference,';',part[position()=$index]/@num,';',part[position()=$index]/@size,';',@unit_of_measurement,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_type,';',part[position()=$index]/@id,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_name,';',part[position()=$index]/@flags,';',part[position()=$index]/@lvm_group,';',part[position()=$index]/@raid_dev,'&#10;')"/> <!-- write partition information -->
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains($type,part[position()=$index]/@p_type) and part[position()=$index]/@size='*'">
        <xsl:call-template name="PrintPartition">
          <xsl:with-param name="index"><xsl:value-of select="number($index)-1"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="reference">beginning</xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@dev,';','beginning;',part[position()=$index]/@num,';',part[position()=$index]/@size,';',@unit_of_measurement,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_type,';',part[position()=$index]/@id,';',part[position()=$index]/@p_name,';',part[position()=$index]/@flags,';',part[position()=$index]/@lvm_group,';',part[position()=$index]/@raid_dev,'&#10;')"/> <!-- write partition information -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="PrintPartition">
          <xsl:with-param name="index"><xsl:value-of select="number($index)-1"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="reference"><xsl:value-of select="$reference"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And voilà: it works perfectly.

There are certainly better or more elegant solutions. (feel free to comment)

- the concat output is ugly but I don't know how to give it a more sexy look
- contains($type,part[position()=$index]/@p_type) is used to test if $type (partition type) matches (test="@p_type=$type" with $type contains 'primary|extended' or 'logical')
- I had to use position()=$index as I navigate in reverse order (from last element to 1st element) (The best way I found to do a sort of foreach in reverse order)
- I need to fix a few bugs: (infinite loop if no partition is declared in a disk section, unique variable size partition is created relative to the end of the disk. While this works, it's not optimal)

(code available here (with few changes): https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/blob/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/lib/dracut/modules.d/51systemimager/do_partitions.xsl)

Answer (score 0):

After extensively googling and learning basics of xslt, it seems that it's what I'm looking for.

(Full source of xml file to treat is available here: https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/blob/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/doc/examples/disk-layout-complex.xml)

```
<!— Sample cut, relevant for this question —>
<config>
      <disk dev="/dev/sda" label_type="msdos" unit_of_measurement="MiB">
              <part num="1" size="500" p_type="primary" flags="boot" />
              <part num="3" size="4096" p_type="primary" />
              <part num="4" size="*" p_type="extended" />
              <part num="7" size="4096" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="5" size="*" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="6" size="2048" p_type="logical" />
              <part num="2" size="1024" p_type="primary" flags="swap" />
      </disk>
</config>
```

xslt has no variable, and thus I need a recursive algorith to achieve the smart sort that will result in correct partition creation order.

The aim is to have xmlstarlet tr layout.xslt disk-layout.xml produce the following output:

```
normal;1;500;primary;;;boot;;
normal;3;4096;primary;;;;;;
reverse;2;1024;primary;;;swap;;
normal;4;*;extended;;;;;;
normal;7;4096;logical;;;;;;
reverse;6;2048;logical;;;;;;
normal;5;*;logical;;;;;;
```

The recursive algorythm would look like:

```
do_partition_template(index, type)
  if partition(index) is same type and if variable_partition is not yet seen:
    print "normal;line"
    do_partition_template(index+1,type)
  if partition(index) is same type and if variable partition has been seen:
    do_partition_template(index+1, type)
    print "reverse;line"
  if(partition(index) is same type and if  size(partition)="*":
    do_partition_template(index+1, type)
    print "normal;line"
  if partition is not the same type:
    do_partition_template(index+1, type)
  fi
call template 1st partition type='primary|extended'
call template 1st partition type='logical'
```

I'm not sure of the recursive form of the algorithm, but what needs to be created in order is:
- list of primary/extended partition to create from beginning of disk
- list of primary/extended partition to create from end of disk
- the primary/extended partition that has size="*"
- list of logical partition to create from beginning of extended partition
- list of logical partition to create from end of extended partition
- the logical partition that has a size of "*"

Being newbee in xsl, it' very complicated for me to solve this.
I used xmlstarlet sel -C -t -m "config/disk[@dev=\"/dev/sda\"]/part" -v "concat(@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@id,';',@p_name,';',@flags,';',@lvm_group,';',@raid_dev)" -n ./disk-layout-complex.xml > do_part.xslt 
To start with my issue, but then it's hard for me to formalize a template that would hit all partitions in 2 scans (one for primary/extended partitions and on for logical partitions)...

Working without variables is somehow not easy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the sort order you want can be achieved as follows (code shortened for clarity):

```bash
DISK_DEV=/dev/sda
DISKS_LAYOUT_FILE=./disk-layout-complex.xml
xmlstarlet sel --text -t \
    -m "config/disk[@dev=\"${DISK_DEV}\"]" \
    -m "part[@p_type='primary']"  -s A:N:L @p_type \
    -v "concat(@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@flags)" -n -b \
    -m "part[@p_type='extended']" -s D:N:L @p_type \
    -v "concat(@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@flags)" -n -b \
    -m "part[@p_type='logical']"  -s D:N:L @size \
    -v "concat(@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@flags)" -n -b \
    ${DISKS_LAYOUT_FILE}
```

Output:

```
1;500;primary;boot
3;4096;primary;
2;1024;primary;swap
4;*;extended;
7;4096;logical;
6;2048;logical;
5;*;logical;
```

Keep in mind you can use several sort keys in XSLT, e.g. ...
    `-m "part[@p_type='primary']" -s A:N:L @p_type -s A:T:L @flags`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it isn't as simple as that. your example only works if extended partition is the one that has a '*' (100%) size. If,instead you have a primary partition with variable size, then the extended partition of a fixed size, your solution will list the primary variable size partition before the extended one. Thus, the primary variable size partition will be created before the extended fixed size partition, eating all available space at that time and leaving no room to create the extended fixed size partition thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I've had another look at this. The list you specified is divided into 
2 by 3 groups:

1. primary/extended partitions preceding a variable-size one (if any), 
   in document order
2. primary/extended partitions following a variable-size one (if any), 
   in reverse document order
3. primary/extended partition of variable size (if any), in document 
   order
4. as 1. but for logical partitions
5. as 2. but for logical partitions
6. as 3. but for logical partition

Here's a complex xmlstarlet command with 6 XPath node tests and 
some shell variables (be careful with quoting) inserted to cut down on repetition. An extra predicate - `[boolean(...)]` - in cases 2 and 5 guards against double output if no variable-size partition exists. No output is generated if no partition is declared.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
disksLayoutFile="${DISKS_LAYOUT_FILE:-./disk-layout-complex.xml}"
diskDev="${DISK_DEV:-/dev/sda}"
#
cfgDisk="config/disk[@dev='${diskDev}']"
type_PE="(@p_type='primary' or @p_type='extended')"
type__L="(@p_type='logical')"
preSibVar_PE="preceding-sibling::part[${type_PE}]/@size='*'"
folSibVar_PE="following-sibling::part[${type_PE}]/@size='*'"
preSibVar__L="preceding-sibling::part[${type__L}]/@size='*'"
folSibVar__L="following-sibling::part[${type__L}]/@size='*'"
valueList="';',@num,';',@size,';',@p_type,';',@flags,';'"
#
xmlstarlet sel --text --template \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type_PE}][@size!='*'][not(${preSibVar_PE})]" \
    -v "concat('beg',${valueList})" -n -b \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type_PE}][@size!='*'][not(${folSibVar_PE})][boolean(${preSibVar_PE})]" \
    -s 'D:N:L' 'count(preceding-sibling::*)' \
    -v "concat('end',${valueList})" -n -b \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type_PE}][@size='*']" \
    -v "concat('beg',${valueList})" -n -b \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type__L}][@size!='*'][not(${preSibVar__L})]" \
    -v "concat('beg',${valueList})" -n -b \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type__L}][@size!='*'][not(${folSibVar__L})][boolean(${preSibVar__L})]" \
    -s 'D:N:L' 'count(preceding-sibling::*)' \
    -v "concat('end',${valueList})" -n -b \
    -m "${cfgDisk}/part[${type__L}][@size='*']" \
    -v "concat('beg',${valueList})" -n -b \
    "${disksLayoutFile}"
```

Output:

```
beg;1;500;primary;boot;
beg;3;4096;primary;;
end;2;1024;primary;swap;
beg;4;*;extended;;
beg;7;4096;logical;;
end;6;2048;logical;;
beg;5;*;logical;;
```

While it would be possible to add more complexity to this command 
(e.g. disk/partition layout issues) I think it would be better placed 
in a proper XSLT script; pushing the limits of shell+xmlstarlet usage 
already.

Comment: Impressive solution, though IMHO difficult to maintain (hardly readable). More over, starting from the last partition (end of disk) is easier (see my validated solution). You have 2 block instead of 3 (1:following sibling and 2:all the other; process for primary/extended then logical)